# React | How to add dynamic new divs like rows

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting trouble while making dynamic new divs. Can anyone help me to do this.

Here is my div.

```
<div className="intent" id="intent1" style={{border:'1px solid #eee'}}>
                <div className="form-group row">
                    <label htmlFor="intent" className="col-sm-1 col-form-label">Intent</label>
                    <div className="col-sm-5">
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" name="indent[]" id="intent1" placeholder="Enter intent"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I need to plus/minus the above div dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manage this through an `array`, add items in `array` when rows are added and remove them accordingly. You can do the following

```js
class App extends React.Component {

constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      rowList: [true]
    };
  }

  add() {
    let rowList = [...this.state.rowList];
    rowList.push(true);
    this.setState({ rowList });
  }

  remove(i) {
    let rowList = [...this.state.rowList];
    rowList.splice(i, 1);
    this.setState({ rowList });
  }

  render() {
    let { rowList } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="intent" id="intent1" style={{border:'1px solid #eee'}}>
        {rowList.map((x, i) => {
          return (
            <div className="form-group row" key={i}>
              <label htmlFor="intent" className="col-sm-1 col-form-label">
                Intent 
              </label>
              <div className="col-sm-5">
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="form-control"
                  name="indent[]"
                  placeholder="Enter intent"
                />
                <button onClick={() => this.remove(i)} >Remove</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          )
        })}
        <button onClick={() => this.add()}>Add New</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's not a ton of context here. Are you trying to show/hide or display multiple dynamically?

You can show/hide just by using a plain old js logical AND operator: `|jsVariable| && <div/>`

You can dynamically display multiple entries of the same div you can do so using the `map` function on a js array: `|jsArray|.map(item => <div/>)`

Comment: i'm trying add/remove div dynamically

Answer (score 0):

Let say you want to add and remove div on the basis of button add and remove.
 Make two buttons 1.  Add Button 2.Remove Button

Make an empty array, in your jsx map the array

```
Array.map((index,item)=>{
 Return <div key={index} > </div>
})
```

This will create div on the basis of array length.

On click of buttons call a function manageDiv()
In manage div check the condition of click (send the parameter of button name so that you can distinguish which button has been clicked)
In manageDiv function push object in array if add and splice if remove button clicked.

```
ManageDiv(type) {
Let Array = this.state.Array
If(type == 'add') {
    Array.push({})
}
else
    Array.splice(0, 1)

This.setState({
    Array
})
}
```